# Identify smartphone from PC programmatically

Tags: android, iphone, activesync

I have a WiFi network with several mobile devices/smartphones (e.g.: iPhone, Samsung). I know their IP addresses, but wish to identify them programatically from my PC without installing any app on them (e.g.: "noldS2" - "GT 9100" - "Android 2.3.5" .. friendly name - device name - os)

There were various methods described on the internet, but ActiveSync seems to be the best. I've investigated  and attempted to connect to the devices using OpenNETCF, RAPI [...] without luck. (I've also investigated other methods like port scans which seem less accurate.)

How could I use ActiveSync to programatically identify the mobile devices connected to WiFi from my PC without needing special apps or permissions from them?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you're going down this path because ActiveSync clients must pass the server a Device ID string during their session handshake, I don't see any way to accomplish that because that conversation will always occur over HTTPS and will therefore be protected from snooping. Even if you could get the device ID it won't tell you the operating system version or anything like that.

I think you'll have to use another technique, and I'm not sure what that might be.

Answer (score 0):

Every mobile device connected to ActiveSync should store quite some information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee202944(v=exchg.80).aspx including: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg675629(v=exchg.80).aspx

As mentioned by @brian-kelly you should be able to get the needed information from the devices HTTP request user-agent string. Put your PC's wifi card in promiscuous mode and process the collected data.